# CSS fixed position div not clickable in Android

Tags: android, css, position, fixed

I have a fixed positioned footer containing buttons as follows:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #97d700;    
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#btn_footer_01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left: 5.13%; 
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index: 9000000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

We would like the footer to stick at the bottom of the viewport, and would like to be able to click on the btn_footer_01 div. However, in Android (target sdk is 17)the onClick() event of the button is not working. It works fine in other browsers like chrome.

What would be a workaround for this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use fixed positioning to be able to address a wide variety of devices including the ones with Android 4.2.2. So, I used absolute positioning:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

(There is a good article about this topic at: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `#footer` is the parent of `#btn_footer_01`.

**Understanding z-index:**

Try to set the `z-index` of the parent to a higher value in stead of setting the child higher. Child will always stay 'on the same level' as their parents. Eg. The parent has `z-index:10;`, and the child `z-index:9000000;` than it acts as `z-index` on level 10 > level 9000000, so `10.9000000`.

---

In your case try the following:

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #97d700;    
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 9000000;
}

#btn_footer_01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left: 5.13%; 
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. The same code works in android 5.1.1, but it does not work in 4.2.2.

Comment: I'm not pro in android development.. Do you use the same browserversion on each androids?

Comment: I use the same WebView to load html content.

Comment: In that case it should work I guess... I can't find another bug in your code.